# WPF Label background png image transparent

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using png image for label background. The blank parts of the label look black. It is should be transparent. How can I do it that?

[image: sample]

```
lbl_popuptext.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri("../../images/icons/appoint_popupbox.png", UriKind.Relative)));
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but quick googling and it should just work. The issue I found was that the parent had a background color and the solution was to remove the background color from the parent. Label may not support ImageBrush as the background. Can you try with just a TextBlock?

Comment: didnt work @TyCobb

Answer (score 1):

I solved. Popup AllowsTransparency property should be true

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is transparent. Check your image first: sometimes the layer that should be transparent, indeed is not. You can use GIMP2 for example to check it, or just insert the image into the PowerPoint project etc.

Comment: I checked. It is transparent